# Remove specific data frame from a list of data frames in R

Tags: r

I have a large list of dataframes. 
I would like to remove one specific dataframe e.g. d2 in this example.

```
my.list
$d1
  y1 y2
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6

$d2
  y1 y2
1  3  6
2  2  5
3  1  4
```

Comment: One approach could be: `my.list[names(my.list) != "d2" ]`

Comment: `my_list[["d2"]] <- NULL`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few options:

```
# assign it to NULL
my.list$d2 = NULL
my.list[["d2"]] = NULL

# remove second item
my.list = my.list[-2]

# subset by  name
my.list = my.list[names(my.list) != "d2"]
```

Answer (score 4):

This will drop the second element from the list.

```
my.list = my.list[-2]
```